# nginx location rewrite but proxy_rewrite off

Tags: nginx, rewrite, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to use nginx for proxying requests to my internal backend.

My configuration reads as follows:

```
location /Shibboleth.sso {
    proxy_pass internal-backend; # ip
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

But, my redirects are always rewritten.. My backend returns a response like https://www.google.de/test and my browser receives https://www.mydomain.de/test

How do I get nginx to just forward the response?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. POUND (my ssl-proxy) by default automatically rewrites every location. I added

```
RewriteLocation 0
```

to the pound.cfg and finally it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my config:

```
  set $s3_bucket '<BUCKETNAME>.s3.amazonaws.com';

  location / {
        send_timeout 5m;
        proxy_read_timeout 240;
        proxy_send_timeout 240;
        proxy_connect_timeout 240;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $s3_bucket;
        proxy_set_header Authorization '';
        proxy_hide_header x-amz-id-2;
        proxy_hide_header x-amz-request-id;
        proxy_ignore_headers "Set-Cookie";
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        proxy_redirect off;
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        proxy_pass http://$s3_bucket;
        }
```

Tested and working. It just passes the URI over to the S3 instance, allowing you to terminate the SSL connection at the proxy. Useful for firewalls and such that require a static IP; as the AWS address space is huge for white-listing purposes.